Classical vs quantum field in beam-splitter
John F. Clauser's 1974 paper (https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevD.9.853),  disproves the classical field theory model for light. In the experiment, a short burst of light from an excited Hg source passes through a set of beam splitters. The detectors for each beam (from a beam splitter) do not simultaneously observe the light from the pulse, implying the light (quantized as a photon) passes through one side of the splitter rather than both sides. This disproves the classical field theory, in which the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality (pg 857, eq. 12) predicts a larger number of coincidence detections. My question is listed below...

As a quality check for the experiment he uses a "classical ... barium-titanate" light source, which does cause coincidence at the detectors as shown in Fig 3, despite being "approximately one photon per pulse"? How is this possible? (pg 859)


Interesting questions but clearly in the “need for focus” category as your post obviously contains 3 questions.

I'm not very familiar with these experiments, but based on some past readings and quick overview of the Clauser article, it seems to me no account was made of the effect of polarization of the light packets. In classical wave optics, light polarization affects how much intensity goes into the transmitted wave and how much into the reflected wave. If polarizations of the wave packets vary widely, then even in classical theory, we can have lowered coincidence rates. Maybe it is lowered enough to save classical theory of light, maybe not, but this should have been analyzed somewhere.

Alternatively, if he had put linear polarizer in front of the "half-silvered" mirror, then tuned the mirror to function as  50/50 splitter for strong light, then the same result - low coincidences - would be a clearer and more convincing argument against the classical wave theory.

Of course, it's possible I'm missing some knowledge that can be found somewhere in his or related papers, where this worry was analyzed and was shown to not matter for the result.

The "classical field theory for light" does not contain beam splitters. It's a free field theory. Is the interaction of light with matter always non-classical? Yes. Why? Because there is no self-consistent classical theory for matter to begin with. Matter in classical physics is not stable. With no disrespect for the quantum optics folks, but trying to classicize the light/matter sector is a lost cause, so the result is not particularly surprising, but it's NOT something that happens because of fundamental issues in quantum mechanics.
